# ActionScript – Default Datatype for Untyped Variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, types, default

if i don't specifically type a variable in my code will it compile as a default datatype?  for example, the "for each ... in" function works best without typing the variable:

```
for each (var element in myArray)
         {
         //process each element
         }
```

does my *element* variable have a datatype?  if it is typed as Object is it better to actually write *element:Object* or does it matter?

**EDIT**

actually, that was a bad example, since the element variable is going to be typed to whatever element is in myArray.

but is that how it works if a variable is untyped?  it will simply become what is passed to it?

here's a better example for my question:

```
var a = "i'm a string"; //does this var becomes a String?

var b = 50.98; //does this var becomes a Number?

var c = 2; //does this var becomes an int?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `for each (var element in myArray)`

The `element` variable doesn't have any data type - it is untyped and thus can hold anything.

And yeah, it is equivalent to writing `element:Object` or `element:*`, but it is always advisable to type your variables - this will help you catch some errors before you run the code. The mxmlc compiler will emit a warning if you don't do this, which can be fixed by typing it as `e:Object` or `e:*`.

---

```
var a = 45.3;  //untyped variable `a`
a = "asd";     //can hold anything

/*
    This is fine:  currently variable `a` contains 
    a String object, which does have a `charAt` function.
*/
trace(a.charAt(1));

a = 23;
/*
    Run time error: currently variable `a` contains 
    a Number, which doesn't have a `charAt` function.
    If you had specified the type of variable `a` when 
    you declared it, this would have been 
    detected at the time of compilation itself.
*/
trace(a.charAt(1)); //run time error


var b:Number = 45.3; 
b = "asd"; //compiler error
trace(a.charAt(1)); //compiler error
```

Comment: strange.  ok, i'll type them, even though i'm using Flash Professional and not Flash Builder, which doesn't give a warning, but i guess it's good to do incase i migrate over to that compiler.  also, the actionscript documentation doesn't type the var in the for each ... in loop:  http://bit.ly/a2tZc9

Comment: Always type. Not only to catch error, but for performance too. Flash being what it is, it is never a bad idea to look for every possible optimization, specially easy ones like these.

Comment: always type your variables and eat your vegetables!